# Shockwave Flash not responding

Tags: google-chrome, video, flash, plugins

When I am trying to load video from multiple site i get the notice "A plug-in (shockwave flash) isn't responding". I have looked up solutions on multiple forums and sites and nothing has worked for me. I have tried doing a browser refresh (I'm using Google Chrome although it does not work in IE either), uninstalling the program the reinstalling it, and refreshing my computer. Please help me be able to watch videos again. I can also not use Pandora or any program using Shockwave.

Comment: everything is now working fine but please tell me how you would have tried solving this for other people and for future reference

Comment: It is no longer working the day after. Please help.